# Automatically Mapping DTO to Entity on Spring Boot API with MapStruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I'm looking for a way to shorten my controllers code.

For example my current controller looks like:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> create(@RequestBody @Valid UserDTO userDTO) {
    val user = userMapper.userDTOToUser(userDTO);
    val createdUser = userService.create(user);
    val responseDTO = userMapper.userToUserDTO(createdUser);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseDTO, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

and of course it can be shorten to:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> create(@RequestBody @Valid UserDTO userDTO) {
    val createdUser = userService.create(userMapper.userDTOToUser(userDTO));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userMapper.userToUserDTO(createdUser), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

but at cost of readability.

So I found few tutorials with a nice and neat approach like:
[auth0.com/blog](https://auth0.com/blog/automatically-mapping-dto-to-entity-on-spring-boot-apis/)
[breakpoint.digital](https://breakpoint.digital/auto-map-object-to-dto-spring-rest/)

but both (and every other I was able to find) use `ModelMapper`.
Is there a way to achieve similar outcome with `MapStruct`?
Extending `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` seems the right way, but couldn't find any info on that.

Based on the tutorials above, I would like to end up with something like:

```
@PostMapping
@OutputDTO(UserDTO.class)
public ResponseEntity<User> create(@RequestBody @Valid @InputDTO(UserDTO.class) User user) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.create(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: I haven't used **MapStruct** before but I guess you should simply try replacing `ModelMapper ` code in above links & rest remains same. e.g. only line `return modelMapper.map(dto, parameter.getParameterType()); `  needs to be done via `MapStruct` & rest structure remains same.

Comment: @SabirKhan
It definitely won't be so easy.  
Tried to change `org.modelmapper.ModelMapper` to `org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers -> new Mappers()` gives error (declared private)
`org.mapstruct.Mapper -> new Mapper()` gives error (abstract class)

Comment: I am not quite getting Why you need to shorten what you have now? What is wrong with doing what you are doing now? It is 3 lines of code

Comment: When I understood it correctly you just want to have the line that calls the `userService`? So for example you can use `User` as a method parameter and MapStruct should be called automatically to map the incoming `UserDTO` to `User`? And the same the other way around for the response? Return `RequestEntity<User>` but internally it should be mapped to `RequestEntity<UserDTO>`?

Comment: @Filip calling mappers for both way mapping is repeating in every single endpoint, so looking for a way to make it automatic (like shown in provided links) seems worth it.

Comment: @chris922 That's good point to define what I want to achieve - updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: @jarobar435 just had a better look at the links. I know exactly what you are trying to achieve. It is a really interesting "problem". There is a way to do this, but it requires something extra from your side (common interface that would be extended by your mappers). The reason is that MapStruct generates code has no runtime knowledge of the mappings. If I have some time this weekend I can try to do some examples in our examples repo. 

On a side note, you can't really return `ResponseEntity<UserDTO>`. I presume your service returns `User`

Comment: @Filip ye, that's of course true - service returns domain object. Overlooked that, thanks.